# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: no matching index found

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting the above error when running the following query. I've not seen it before, can't find any documentation about it, and I'm not doing anything unusual or anything I've not done before. Can anyone shed any light on it, please?

```
const getUserProjects = async () => {
    return await useFireStore
    .collection('projects')
    .where('paid','==',true)
    .where('ownerId','==', `${currentUser.uid}`)
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let projects = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            projects.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        });
        setUserProjects(projects);
    });
};
```

It is a 'new' query in that I've just added it to the code, so I might expect the error in the console that gives a link for a new composite index to be created or whatever it's called, but I'm just getting this instead:

[image: Firestore Console Error]

EDIT: I have tried manually creating an Index, but I still get the same error. I have also got a query on the same page which is exactly the same apart from the collection name, and that works fine.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing today

Comment: Hi, no, I'm still getting the error. Maximum number of composite indexes is 200, so it's not that either. Very frustrating

Comment: Ok, I've tried setting up a completely new project and every query that would normally result in the console outputting a message (and link) to create an Index is now just outputting the above error.

Comment: Getting the same error. Filed GitHub issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3583

Comment: Thanks Clive, I've submitted a critical bug through the Firebase support system

Comment: UPDATE: Just received this from Google: "...We have received several reports similar to yours and the engineering team is already working to solve it. I added your case to the developers affected by this issue to continue pushing the solution..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an internal bug in the SDK.

Firebase team is working on it, follow the issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152).

Answer (score 1):

That's a known [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) with *Client SDKs*. However the Admin SDK still works as usual and returns throws an error containing the link to create index and can be used a workaround. Just use the Firebase Functions Emulator locally with the Admin SDK.

Use an existing Firebase project or create a new one for this:

```
firebase init functions
```

Copy the following function:

```
export const getIndexLink = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const snap = await admin.firestore()...get()
        // Paste your query here
        response.send(snap.size, "matched documents");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        response.send(error.message)
        // This error will contain the index creation link
    }
});
```

Run the function emulator:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

Open a browser and paste your `getIndexLink` function's URL and you should have the URL to create index there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you must create an index for your "where" and "orderBy" conditions in the indexes column in your cloud firestore.

Official documentation:

1. [Manage indexes in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=0#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message)
2. [Indexes and pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview?authuser=0#indexes_and_pricing)

Comment: Hello Miguel,. Thanks you for your time. I have over 30 indexes in the current App, without any problem. That's one of the reasons I'm so surprised by this error. As I said in my comment above, I suspect it's related to my Blaze subscription.

Comment: Just stumbled on this as well... Usually firebase would give you a link to create the index automatically for you. I just upgraded firebase-tools, so suspecting that isn't happening anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new index manually from firestore console

1. Go to the Cloud Firestore section of the Firebase console.
2. Go to the Indexes tab and click Add index.
3. Enter the name of the collection and set the fields you want to use to sort the index.
4. Click Create.

more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=0#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message

Comment: yeah this solution seems obvious but is not working either for me