# Firestore missing index build link is not logged into logcat in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I do a firestore query in my android app, if the firesotre index which is required to execute the query is not currently available, firestore used to log a URL to logcat, which I could click to build the required index correctly.

Today when I added a new query to my app, this link was not logged, and only the exception was logged telling that the index required to execute the query is missing.

```
    ....
    ....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) ~[na:0.0]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.
    at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:541) ~[na:0.0]
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:115) ~[na:0.0]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I am using following firebase version.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
```

What could be the reason for this? Is there a way to get the link to build the index, without having to build the index manually in the firebase console?

Comment: This is a known issue on many platforms. The client SDKs are not returning index creation URL. You can try emulating a cloud function locally that runs your query using Admin SDK as explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/firebase-index-required-but-no-link-provided/68388387#68388387). Admin SDK still throws an error containing the index creation link. There's [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) for the same in JS SDK too.

Comment: Have you tried to create it manually in the Firebase Console?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Good to hear that, Dharmaraj.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. I could create the index through the console, and the query works now. But it is time consuming to create the exact index required for the query manually, and it would be great if firebase can provide the link again.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, it would be great to have that explanation as an answer for this issue, instead of a comment, so that it is more visible for everyone.

Comment: Hey @JMA I've posted an answer for similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374000/uncaught-error-in-snapshot-listener-firebaseerror-no-matching-index-found/68438644#68438644) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/firebase-index-required-but-no-link-provided/68388387#68388387) :)

Comment: So I will flag this case as duplicated then. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase index required but no link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/firebase-index-required-but-no-link-provided)