# How to orderBy the firebase collection containing only one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to orderBy by the "collectionGroup" that contains only one object and that object contains an array. like this [image]

***The collectionGroup named "Calculations" contains only one Doc named "0" and that Doc contains an array,*** Now I'm trying to order them using the orderBy() method but it's not working.

Here is my code.

```
  calculations = await db
    .firestore()
    .collectionGroup("Calculations")
    .orderBy("symbol", "asc")
    .limit(limit)
    .get()
  }
```

As u can see in the picture there is a value "symbol" in each array so I tried using that to order but was unable to do so, firebase says no matching index was found.

Comment: You cannot order the array this way. You should store each of those array entries into documents in a collection and order it that way

Comment: I want to paginate it, is there any other way through which i can paginate without applying orderBy(). Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue with query:**

You cannot use `orderBy` or `array-contains` like operators on an array of objects unless you know the complete object as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68188623). You should ideally use sub-collections instead of arrays. "Calculations" seems to be a sub-collection already then if you store the calculation in it's documents instead of an array in a single document, your query should work fine.

**Issue with index:**

If you see "No matching index" error then that means the query requires an index. Either you can [create index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) manually from the Firebase Console or create it using the link thrown in error (used to be thrown). There's an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) with client SDKs that the index required errors are not including the link to create index. There are issue where the index is created manually but isn't working as expected.

However, the Admin SDK still throws in error containing the click to create index link and I'll recommend you to try running your query in a cloud function locally using Cloud functions emulators and use the link thrown in error.

You can refer to these answers for detailed explanation on how to create index using the link thrown my Admin SDK:

1. [FirebaseError: No matching index found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374000/uncaught-error-in-snapshot-listener-firebaseerror-no-matching-index-found/68438644#68438644)
2. [Firebase index required but no link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/firebase-index-required-but-no-link-provided/68388387#68388387)

Comment: I want to paginate it, is there any other way through which i can paginate without applying orderBy(). Any Idea ?

Comment: @MuhammadHassaanAther no, if they are in an array then you'll end up fetching the whole array. It'll be best to split the calculations in their own documents then you can paginate it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to re-structure your data - probably move your "array" contents into a sub-collection of documents.  Firestore "arrays" are remarkably not useful - the reason I put "arrays" in scare-quotes is:

Firestore "arrays" are ABSOLUTELY NOT ARRAYS. They are ORDERED LISTS, generally in the order they were added to the array. The SDK presents them to the CLIENT as arrays, but Firestore itself does not STORE them as actual arrays - THE NUMBER YOU SEE IN THE CONSOLE is the order, not an index. Matching elements or querying in an array (arrayContains, e.g.) requires matching the WHOLE element - if you store an ordered list of objects, you CANNOT query the "array" on sub-elements.

The client SDKs generally present the values in the arrays/"ordered lists" to you as an array - which has more to do with most languages not having a primitive element that is an ordered list.